# felt with past participle

Tags: grammar, verbs, past-participles

We say “I felt honored to have won such a prestigious award.”

In the first sentence, we use felt+past participle form. Why we use past participle form? is it any rule like be+past participle?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not really. *Honored* here is functioning as an adjective, not a verb. It's exactly parallel to _I felt **happy**, **angry**, **tired**, **suspicious**, **elated**, **dejected**. Some of them are past participles, some are not, but in this construction they are all adjectives.

Many past participles can be used as adjectives, but not all: you just have to learn them.

Comment: Thank you, Colin. So there is no rule behind it? Is there any special name for those adjectives?